# Efficiency of list operations in functional languages

Tags: functional-programming

In functional languages like Racket or SML, we usually perform list operations in recursive call (pattern matching, list append, list concatenation...). However, I'm not sure the general implementation of these operations in functional languages. Will operations like create, update or delete elements in a list return a whole new copy of a list? I once read in a book an example about functional programming disadvantage; that is, every time a database is updated, a whole new copy of a database is returned.

I questioned this example, since data in FP is inherently immutable, thus the creating lists from existing lists should not create a whole new copy. Instead, a new list is simply just a different collection of reference to existing objects in other lists, based on filtering criteria.

For example, list `A = [a,b,c]`, and list `B=[1,2,3]`, and I created a new list that contains the first two elements from the existing lists, that is `C=[a,b,1,2]`. This new list simply contains references to `a,b,` from `A` and `1,2` from `B`. It should not be a new copy, because data is immutable.

So, to update an element in a list, it should only take a linear amount of time find an element in a list, create a new value and create a new list with same elements as in the old list except the updated one. To create a new list, the running environment merely updates the next pointer of the previous element. If a list is holding non-atomic elements (i.e. list, tree...), and only one atomic element in one of the non-atomic element is updated, this process is recursively applied for the non-atomic element until the atomic element is updated as described above. **Is this how it should be implemented?**

If someone creates a whole deep copy of a list every time a list is created from existing lists/added/updated/deleted/ with elements, they are doing it wrong, aren't they?

Another thing is, when the program environment is updated (i.e. add a new key/value entry for a new variable, so we can refer to it later), **it doesn't violate the immutable property of functional programming, is it?**

Comment: You might find a part of the answers to your questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658887/functional-programming-immutable-data-structure-efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct! FP languages with immutable data will **NEVER** do a deep copy (unless they are really poorly implemented). As the data **is** immutable there are never any problems in reusing it. It works in exactly the same way with all other structures. So for example if you are working with a tree structure then at most only the actual tree will be copied and never the data contained in it.

So while the copying sounds very expensive it is much less than you would first think if you coming from an imperative/OO background (where you really do have to copy as you have mutable data). And there are many benefits in having immutable data.