# Create a list by consing vs tail-call accumulator

Tags: functional-programming, sml

For example, one function creates a list via consing:

```
fun example1 _ _ [] = []
  | example1 f g (x::xs) =
    if f x
    then (g x)::(example1 f g xs)
    else x::(example1 f g xs)
```

One creates a list via tail-call accumulator:

```
fun example2 f g xs =
    let fun loop acc [] = acc
          | loop acc (x::xs') =
            if f x
            then loop (acc@[(g x)]) xs'
            else loop (acc@[x]) xs'
    in
        loop [] xs
    end
```

to produce the same list given the same arguments.

Which function has better running time?

Does append operation `@` traverse to the end of the list to append and end up with the same running time with consing solution, but using much less space and slightly more complicated code?

Does consing or appending create an entire new element (deep copy of object), even if there's no change to the original element or it simply reuses the existing elements?

This question gives a more concrete example for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585971/efficiency-of-list-operations-in-functional-languages/15591140?noredirect=1#15591140)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x :: xs` creates one new list cell whose head is `x` and whose tail is `xs`. It does not create a copy of `xs` - neither deep nor shallow. So it's an O(1) operation.

`xs @ [x]` creates a shallow copy of `xs` with the change that the tail of the previously last node is now `[x]`. This is an `O(n)` operation.

So the time complexity of your `example1` function is `O(n)` and that of your `example2` function is `O(n^2)`. Both functions consume `O(n)` auxiliary space. `example1` because of its stack usage and `example2` because `@` creates lists on the heap that aren't part of the resulting list.

If you change `example2` to use `::` rather than `@` and then use `List.rev` on the result when you reach the end of the list, it's running time will be `O(n)`, but it will still be somewhat slower than `example1` because of the additional cost of reversing the list at the end. However that might be an acceptable price to pay to be able to handle large lists without stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful that you remind me `x::xs` is just a cons cell. Initially, it kept giving me impression that a whole new list is created with new references to existing objects in memory because of my very early misconception when learning FP is that immutability = copying. Essentially, only a cons cell is created and we have a new list. Seems neat. In the end, it's the trade-off between space and time.

Comment: I was not sure the underlying implementation actually mutate the tail pointer. Or maybe it  perform a chain operations of creating new cells.

Comment: i.e. we want to change a list  `[1,2,3,4]` to  `[1,2,3,5]`; the element `4` will be discarded and a new cell that hold `[5,[]]` is created. Since element `4` must be updated to the new cell we created, element  `3`  will also need updating because its tail pointer needs change; as a result, a new cell that hold `3`  and `[5,[]]` is created and form the list `3::[5,[]]` . This process repeats until all elements are updated. Doing it this way, it will be much slower because a whole new list is created as oppose to mutate a single element.

Comment: @Amumu The most important property of immutable data structures is that you can still access the old structure after you've made a change. So no, it's not possible for an implementation to implement any operations by mutating the pointers of the existing list (unless it can prove that there are no references to the old list (or any of its sublists) anywhere - but implementations don't generally perform that kind of analysis as far as I know). And yes, replacing single elements at the end or middle of a list, will be slow (i.e. `O(n)`). That's not generally something you do with linked lists.

Comment: So, the standard way to change the list is to create a new list to reserve immutability property. And for mutable in the middle, I should use `Refs` or `Array`.

Comment: @Amumu If you want efficient random access, you'll need an array. Using refs will get rid of the copying, but it won't fix the fact that random access into a linked list (whether it's mutable or immutable) takes O(n) time.